# Photo requirements for Vietnam e-visa application

Tags: visas, vietnam, e-visas

Can you take your own photo if it meets the requirements rather than getting passport photos?

The application asks for a scan of your passport and an additional image where you are not smiling, no glasses, white background. Does this have to be done by a passport photo company or can you take your own photo?

Comment: Probably you can. I did the paper visa with them just before the eVisa program was launched and gave them photos taken and printed by myself, so I don't image the eVisa would require differently but let's wait if someone says differently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed. The photo then needs to be approved so if it doesn't fit the 
requirments it won't pass.

Photo requirements as follows from the [GOV website](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/faq):

> ## 1. What photos are required for the application?
>
> Two photos of the applicant must be uploaded:
>
> - Portrait photo (4x6cm): Looking straight and without glasses.
> - Passport data page: Full page including photo, personal information and ICAO line

There are even services for taking the photo yourself and cropping it online like this one [here](https://www.idphotodiy.com/how-to/make-vietnam-passport-visa-photo-online.php).